# How do I know what is included in a loop with reading assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

So we are currently working on reverting assembly back to C....

All we are given is that the function is

```
long part2(long x, long y);
```

and by disassembling the object file we obtain :

```
0:  48 8d 04 7f             lea    (%rdi,%rdi,2),%rax
4:  48 c1 e0 04             shl    $0x4,%rax
8:  48 8d 56 1f             lea    0x1f(%rsi),%rdx
c:  48 85 f6                test   %rsi,%rsi
f:  48 0f 49 d6             cmovns %rsi,%rdx
13: 48 c1 fa 05             sar    $0x5,%rdx
17: 48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
1a: c3                      retq
```

so far I have something that looks like this :

```
long someVar = 3x;
someVar = someVar << 4;
long anotherVar = y + 31;
//here is where I start to loose it....
if (y&y) {
    anotherVar>>5;
...
```

How do I know when to close the if statement?

Comment: If there is no conditional jump or branch, what makes you think this represents an `if` statement?  If there is, why doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks for the quick response. Through my googling, I found that the "test" instruction sets the condition code to S1&S2 so I thought that meant something like if (y&y) then do something, im guessing i was incorrect to assume that?

Comment: It sets/rsets flags in hthe flags register. Another instruction is required to conditionally transfer control as instructed by the flag/s.   'test' does not transfer control.  The IP is advanced to the next instruction.

Comment: The `test` instruction works with the `cmovns` instruction. `cmovns` is short for *conditional move if something*, where the letters after `cmov` indicate the condition to check. I'm just guessing that `ns` means *not sign*. You need to look at the instruction definitions, e.g. in [this manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html).

Answer (score 2):

In assembler, an `if`  is usually compiled as a test and a conditional jump. And sometimes an extra unconditional jump to skip the `else` part. You know when the `if` ends looking at where the jump goes. But be aware that optimizations can mess with the code and make it difficult to understand.

For example:

```
if (x)
{ /* if_code * }
next_instruction;
```

becomes:

```
text x,x
jz Label
/* if_code */
Label:    
next_instruction
```

In you particular example, however, there is no jump. Instead the `CMOVNS` instruction is used. That is a conditional move. That is, if the `NS` condition holds, that is the `S` flag is not set, then the value from `%rsi` is moved into `%rdx`. And that is the only instruction in the condition!

But note that the condition flag is `S` (sign), not `Z` (zero). So the move is done if `%rsi >= 0`.

Comment: Thanks @rodrigo! The first part makes things a lot more clear for me.
I also understand your explaination for the CMOVNS, but what still is unclear to me is what the "test" instruction is for then?

Comment: @mir-aclewhip: The `TEST A,B` instruction tests the value of `A & B` (being `&` binary-and). Frequently `A` and `B` are the same, then the value checked is simply that one. What that means is that the CPU sets its flags depending of that value (Zero, Sign, Parity flags). Then the `CMOVNS` instruction uses the value of the Sign flag to decide whether to move or not.

Comment: ahh gotcha. Thanks @rodrigo